# How to add icon to push notification using firebase-nativescript

Tags: firebase, push-notification, icons, nativescript

I am trying to add white icon with transparent background for my push natifications using nativescript with firebase and angular. I have generated icons using https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit

but no matter what i do i get just white square
So far i have tried:

1. adding default icon to manifest

   meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
       android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
2. passing icon via message it self

   "icon": "ic_stat_ac_unit",

If nothing above added nativescript icon in notifications shows fine.

Another related question would be how to add image on the left hand side of notfication like instagram and other are doing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW0rz.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are using right file name, in #1 you mentioned notification_icon and in #2 you have mentioned ic_stat_ac_unit. Just trying to make sure notification_icon is valid file name within drawable folders.

Comment: Yes i am sure. Names are different because i took manifest line from stackowerflow example but not from my. but yes - I am sure i am using good name

Comment: I have made simple icon just put there white dot and it worked. My guess is that the should not be any transparent dots on icon just white 100% opacity or none? Because icon generator made aliasing does to make icon more smooth? If yes how to generate nice icons from logo?

Answer (score 0):

It started to work after i removed android folder undel platforms and rebuild whole solution